# asking for tag rename

Tags: discussion

The [allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) tag should be converted to [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) How can that be done?

Comment: This is possible through moderator intervention - why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: @RoryM The word scope is much more widely used in this context over the SE network. Also, it is far less cumbersome, and covers the exact territory of allowed-questions. Thoughts?

Comment: (a) I assume you mean [meta-tag:allowed-questions] `[meta-tag:allowed-questions]`. (b) This should be `discussion`, not `feature-request`, as it does not require input from developers.

Comment: @TRiG well, whatever. I noticed you have no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag editing is something that can be done with a reputation of 4k and above.  If this is the actual desire of the group, then I think it should be vocalized here so popular support could be shown to a moderator.

Allowed-questions isn't unique to Bio-SE, and seems a little more specific than Scope.  Perhaps both are in order?